# Routes Leading me to a Different Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink, routes

I have a routes folder

```
resources :groups
```

In my `GroupsController` here are some actions

```
def new
  @group = Group.new
end

def update
end

def show
  @groups = Group.find(params[:id])
end
```

When I run rake routes I see

```
new_group GET    /groups/new(.:format)    groups#new
```

So now in my html page I have

```
a.btn.btn-primary href="/groups/new"
```

The funny thing is whenever I click on the link, it tells me

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups"}
```

I actually do have a route match for the show action. I also checked and do not have any filters that are redirecting me to the show action in my `GroupsController`. I have no idea why it's redirecting me to show. What's wrong and how do I fix this? I must be missing something obvious.

UPDATE

If I go and remove the show action from the resources method like so

```
resources :groups, except: [:show]
```

Then it tells me that it could not find an `update` action.

## SOLVED

I found out in my `new.html` page there was a call to `group_path`, when in reality it should `groups_path`

Comment: Instead of writing the route yourself, try using the `new_group` helper method. So instead of this: `a.btn.btn-primary href="/groups/new"` use this: `a.btn.btn-primary href="#{new_group}"`.

Comment: Sorry, no difference. Still leads me to a routing error page. And for reference it should be `new_group_path` or `new_group_url`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the trailing `_path` :/ This is weird indeed... I'll dig it up, hope to be back with something helpful.

Comment: out of interest, what does your `update` action do? redirect to `show` by any chance?

Comment: Update action does nothing currently. I updated my question with some more code from the `Groups` Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out in my new.html page there was a call to `group_path`, when in reality it should `groups_path`.